# REGARDING @pathVariable annotation

Tags: spring-boot, api

what are the uses of @pathVaraible annotations in springboot?

actually i was just learning How to create rest apis but i need some depth explanation of @pathVariable annotation what are advantages and instead of these what we can do

Answer (score 0):

@pathvariable annotations basically helps you bind your parameters of dynamic methods handling the request to the REST endpoints which in turn makes it more readable and intuitive.
The other alternatives, although they work in a similar fashion to this, are:-

@RequestParam: This annotation is used to extract query parameters from the URL. Unlike path variables, query parameters are optional and are not required for the endpoint to function correctly.

@RequestBody: This annotation is used to extract the request body from a REST endpoint. This is useful when the data being sent to the endpoint is complex or too large to be included as a query parameter.

@RequestHeader: This annotation is used to extract headers from a REST endpoint's request. This is useful when the endpoint requires specific information from the header, such as authentication or authorization tokens.

@ModelAttribute: This annotation is used to bind request parameters to a model object. This is useful when the endpoint requires multiple parameters that need to be grouped together into a single object.